# Correct word when "introducing" someone to an organization

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to tell an organization to "say" or "introduce" the staff that are supposed to take a course in our organization. The only word that comes to my mind is "introduce" which I know is wrong.

> Please "introduce" the staff that will participate in the course.

Comment: Is this in advance of the course?  During?  Or do you want a point person to send you a list of participants?

Comment: Why do you think that *introduce* is wrong? What action are you actually trying to describe?

Comment: It is in advance of the course. I want the other organization to send the list.

Comment: I think "send details about" works here.

Comment: "Please identify the staff who will be attending the course."

Answer (score 1):

**Correct word when “introducing” someone to an organisation**
(It is in advance of the course. I want the other organisation to send the list.

From the above I would presume that the other organisation is possibly a client, and you are providing a training course or similar.

In this case. the request should be formal and polite.

Send us the list of the Guys coming is not a good option

Try something like this.

**Could you please forward the details of the members of your party who will be attending the previously arranged ***** Course/course on(about****), starting on the 4th July. Please  included details of any special needs or other information that you think we might need to know.**

However, I know nothing of your organisation. If you are offering diving courses or advanced white water rafting. Then rather than suggesting what you need, you will have to be more definite and provide a list.

**We will require the following details** suggests you must give us. This should then be followed by a list or even a form for the client to provide/Complete.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was a thorough answer. Do you have any recommendations how I can write as well as you? Or it is impossible because I'm not native?

Comment: The easiest way to study writing for business it to look at what large companies use. Look at web sites, send for brochures and magazines. However I would not use something from a Western Hotel in Shanghai; for example Because you would not know if it was written by a native English speaker. Also target you client base. Look at literature from those Countries/regions.